# Modified convexity definition on manifolds allowing non-unique minimising geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am interested in subsets $A \subset M$ of a connected, complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with the following property: for every $p,q \in A$, at least one minimising geodesic from $p$ to $q$ in $M$ is contained in $A$. Is there a name for this property? It is more general than convexity and weak convexity as defined in Chavel's *Riemannian Geometry: A Modern Introduction*, since it includes e.g. `bands' on a cylinder.

Comment: This is the same as definition (A2) in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198530/notions-of-convexity

Comment: Whitehead, 1931 ('Convex regions in the geometry of paths') refers to regions whose points are joined by unique paths as *simple convex* regions. Unfortunately, I think there's been a nomenclature change over the past 80 years, and now 'convex' means what Whitehead called 'simple convex'.